# How far to nearest/next prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

Is there is metric to know how far we are from the nearest prime number. For example if my number is 38, then we are 3 numbers away from 41?

If such a metric doesn't exist, is there an upper bound saying that we must find a prime number before (say) the next 300 numbers?

Comment: Do you mean the "nearest" prime number, or the "next" prime number? I ask because $37$ is closer to $38$ than $41$ is.

Comment: There is no global upper bound. For example, the numbers $n! + 2, \ldots, n! + n$ are $n - 1$ consecutive composite numbers, and obviously we can choose $n$ to make $n - 1$ as large as we want.

Comment: For large numbers, the nearest prime is very difficult to determine. And from some magnitude on, it is not feasible in practice. For example, for $10^{10^{100}}$

Comment: There are bounds on how far away the *next* prime number can be, but these are not "sharp" bounds as normally formulated (i.e. they give a range, not the exact next prime).

Comment: @GTonyJacobs, The next one. (But I would be interested in the other case as well)

Comment: We know the average distance, but getting firm limits has proved difficult. There has been no radical improvement on Bertrand's postulate as far as I know.

Comment: @almagest:  Bertrand's postulate has been vastly improved upon.  Google for *prime gaps upper bound*.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1083

Comment: @hardmath These are bounds that hold for all sufficiently large $N$. That is interesting theoretically, but not the same as a Bertrand-type bound.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For concrete bounds on prime gaps that improve upon "[Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate)", which (in a slightly weakened form) states:

$$ \forall n \ge 3 \;\exists p \text{, a prime s.t. } n < p < 2n $$

see [a brief summary on the Prime Pages](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/gaps.html#bounds).  In particular:

$$ \forall n \ge n_0 \;\exists p \text{, a prime s.t. } n < p < (1+\epsilon) n $$

holds for $\epsilon = 1/16597$ and $n_0 = 2010760$, proved by Schoenfeld in 1976.  The citation given is to P. Ribenboim's *The new book of prime number records*, 3rd edition (Springer-Verlag, 1995).  This has surely been improved upon as far as reducing $\epsilon \gt 0$.

**Added:** Pierre Dusart has proven concrete bounds of the form:

$$ \forall n \ge n_0 \;\exists p \text{, a prime s.t. } n < p < (1+e(n)) n $$

where $e(n)$ tends to zero as $n\to \infty$.  In [this arXiv.org paper from 2010](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442) he shows that we can take $n_0 = 396738$ and the function:

$$ e(n) = \frac{0.04}{\ln^2 n} $$

Comment: $\forall n \ge 2$, indeed.

Comment: @TonyK: Yes, for the bound $n \lt p \lt 2n$.  But see the article linked for stronger form $n \lt p \lt 2n-2$, which requires $n \gt 3$.  I settled on the weak form of bound and $n \ge 3$ for petty consistency with "improved" statements, and now we could use $n \ge 2$ at top.